# Jquery On Click, Hide and Show div Multi Items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Can someone help me?

I want to hide div when clicking, but other div is still active, this code actually works fine but this code is less effective and time consuming, is there a way to make it easier or is there a similar way, this I will not only input 3 items but more than 10 item

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "div.myDiv", function(e) {
    $('.goo').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goo2').css('display', 'block');
    $('.goo3').css('display', 'block');
  });
})

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "div.myDiv2", function(e) {
    $('.goo').css('display', 'block');
    $('.goo2').css('display', 'none');
    $('.goo3').css('display', 'block');
  });
})

$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "div.myDiv3", function(e) {
    $('.goo').css('display', 'block');
    $('.goo2').css('display', 'block');
    $('.goo3').css('display', 'none');
  });
})
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.myDiv2 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.myDiv3 {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.goo {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
}

.goo2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
}

.goo3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test1
</div>
<div class="myDiv2">
  <div class="goo2"></div>
  Test2
</div>
<div class="myDiv3">
  <div class="goo3"></div>
  Test3
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of classes, compared to IDs, is that they don't have to be unique and can be reused, avoiding you to repeat your code.

```js
const $allGoos = $(".goo");

$(".myDiv").click(function() {
  $allGoos.show();
  $(this).find('.goo').hide();
});
```

```css
.myDiv {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 10px;
}

.goo {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test1
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test2
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test3
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test4
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test5
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test6
</div>
<div class="myDiv">
  <div class="goo"></div>
  Test7
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a class to identify every element. You should use id for that. But in this case, you can apply a set of rules for all your element by using only one or two classes.
So by using jQuery you can shorten your code above like this...

```js
$(".goo").click(function (e) {
  $(".goo").css("display","block")
  $(this).css("display","none")
});
```

```css
.myDiv
{
  border:1px solid gray;
  margin:10px;
}
.goo
{
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
  border-radius: 5px;
  width:90%;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"> </div>
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"></div>
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"></div>
      Test3
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why `preventDefault()`, because you're not submitting a form. Also, `.css("display","block")` and `.css("display","none")` can be simplified to `.show()` and `.hide()`

Comment: @Vuien No problem. You could also use `hide()` and `show()` as well. jQuery has very useful functions. But I wanted you to see what happened so I used your `css()` approach.

Comment: @JeremyThille I'm using Visual Code. I have installed shortcuts for jQuery so it was self filled. I removed it. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyThille Like I said in my comment to Vuien. I am aware of `.hide()` and `.show()`. I wanted him to see what happened using his own approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could give all the elements the same "goo" class. Like this

```
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"> </div>
    Test1
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"></div>
    Test2
  </div>
  <div class="myDiv">
    <div class="goo"></div>
      Test3
  </div>
```

and then set to all to show on click and set the element that was clicked to hide using the "this" keyword

```
$(function(){
     $('.myDiv').on("click",function(){
         $('.goo').show();
         $(this).find('.goo').hide();
     });    
 })
```

Comment: There might be a problem attaching the click handler to `.goo`. Indeed, these are basically background divs. If there is anything in front of it, it won't catch the click event. The user will click `Test1`, but nothing will happen, because the text blocks the click to the `.goo` that's below.